# Deriving a parameter in optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, dynamical-systems, linear-programming, economics

**My question:**

[image]

**My solution for the part (i)**
[image]

Hopefully my solution is correct. Especially check the budget constraint.

If it is correct, then my actual question to you is the second part (i). I cannot derive $\alpha$    In this part, only help me derive alpha. I can do the rest of them. I cannot derive alpha. For that please give me a hint or a solution thank you.

---

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for  (i): The budget  constraint is $$y-[\alpha(c+p_1)+(1-\alpha)p_1]x_1-p_2x_2$$

The extra cost $c$ hat to be added to $p_1$

And the partial derivatives of the lagrange function are

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial x_1}=\alpha\cdot qx_1+(1-\alpha)x_2-\lambda[\alpha(c+p_1)+(1-\alpha)p_1] =0$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial x_2}=\alpha\cdot qx_1+(1-\alpha)x_1-\lambda p_2 =0$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda}=y-[\alpha(c+p_1)+(1-\alpha)p_1]x_1-p_2x_2=0$$

Comment: how and why can you write budget constarint in such way? I understand the part $\alpha(p_1+c)x_1+p_2x_2$ but why dou you write $(1-\alpha )x_1$? i guess you write this for the consumer who doesnt pay to upgrade. right?

Comment: @B11b He does pay for upgrade. You have two kinds of prices for $x_1$. One price without upgrade $p_1$ and one price with upgrade $c+p_1$. And $\alpha$ is the proportion of the price of the upgraded product 1. The proportion sum up to 1. Thus the not upgraded price is $(1-a)p_1$.

Numerical example: If the price for upgrade is $2$, the price without upgrade is $4$, the proportion is $0.5$ and $x_1=2$, then we the consumer has to pay for good 1: $(0.5\cdot (4+2)+0.5\cdot 2)\cdot 2=8$.

Comment: @B11b Another way of thinking. The proportion is $0.5$ is and $x_1=2$. Thus we have 1 good with upgrade and  1 good without upgrade: $1\cdot (4+2)+1\cdot (2)=8$

Comment: Dear @callculus I have also added the other parts of the question with my answers. Please check it and give me your pretty helpful hints. I also could not do part 5 but I wrote my idea about that. Thank you so much

Comment: @B11b I´ll have a look at your answers. It will takes some time since it is almost midnight here in Germany. I think I can give you an reply tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: thank you so much. okay no problem. Whenever you want. I just studying exams and I try to learn them. So I am only waiting for your ideas, time is not important. :)

Comment: Dear @callculus when you find a time, please tell me your ideas. Thanks.